# eclemma 1 of 2 branch not covered in Junit

Tags: java, junit, eclemma

JUnit file

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    ...
    @Test
    public void testSomeContextFailure() throws Exception {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        try {
            sc.SomeContext(null,null);
            fail("IllegalArg expected");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeContextSuccess() throws Exception {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        SomeContext in = new SomeContext();
        in.setName("something");
        in.setId("5");
        in.setPoints(SomePoint.X);
        try {
            assertNotNull(sc.SomeContext(in,null));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Java File

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private InsuredDAO insuredDAO;

    @Override
    public context SomeContext(context c, unused u) throws Exception {
        if(c == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        insuredDAO.increaseValue(c);
        if(c.getPoints() != null) {
            ...do something
        }
        return c;
}
```

In java file `if(c == null)` was highlighted yellow with message saying 1 of 2 branches not covered.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

highlighted green

```
insuredDAO.increaseValue(c);
```

Everything on and below this line is red

What am I missing? (JUnit test was passed on both but why it isn't covered)?

Comment: an exception in (exactly) this line!?

Comment: what do you mean? exception happened in sc.SomeContext(null,null); where it suppose to throw illegalArg exception and it did....the problem is that the test passed but the coverage isnt covered for anything below the exception

Comment: no,no, i mean the `insuredDAO.increaseValue(c);` line/instruction ... and not an exception that you test/expect.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit too late, but if someone else comes across this...
First:
You have two tests of which one of them fails. As the only test, that went through, tested the "null" value, eclemma marks the if statement as "partially covered". -> null check was tested, but with the given Object, it was not.
It doesn't work that way like a debugger "the test ran up until this line, then it failed, but everything it did until this stage will be analyzed". eclemma just analyzes fully run (and succeeded) tests.
Second:
In your class you have `insuredDAO.increaseValue(c);`, which is autowired. In my tests I have to mock this Object, otherwise it will fail with a `NullPointerException` at that line because autowiring is not done in junit tests, therefore `insuredDAO` is null and the method call will throw a `NullPointerException`.
Should have popped up in your IDE, though ;)